# How to add telerik button to winform in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, telerik

I'm working on a WinForms app.
I have the following code which creates a telerik button:

```c#
this.back_btn = new Telerik.WinControls.UI.ActionButtonElement();

this.back_btn.Location = new Point(30, 0);
this.back_btn.Size = new Size(30, 30);
this.back_btn.ShouldApplyTheme = true;

private Telerik.WinControls.UI.ActionButtonElement back_btn;
```

But how do I add this button to the `Form`?

So far, I've tried `this.Controls.Add(this.back_btn);` but the compiler cannot convert the telerik button into a normal control, so this method does not work. I've searched the telerik forums and docs but cannot find any appropriate method.

Comment: I don't use telerik but a quick search led me to [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/buttons/dropdownbutton/tooltips) where it shows that `ActionButtonElement` is not supposed to be used as a regular control. It's rather an "element" used as part of other controls. You probably want to use [`RadButton`](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/buttons/button/overview) instead.

Comment: Oh you're right, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from **41686d6564**'s comment to my question.
I was using an element (ActionButtonElement) instead of a control.

Fixed it by:

- converting my button to a `RadButton`
- adding it to the Form normally (ie `this.Controls.Add(...)`)